# Building Mono's class libraries on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, mono, cygwin, compilation

Can anyone provide a step by step instruction on how to build the Mono class library (namely System.dll and mscorlib.dll) on windows? I can already build the core libmono/mono stuff using msvc.

I've already looked at the following (none of them work...)

1. http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2005/02/07/monowindows.html
2. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/mono_on_windows.aspx
3. http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_on_Windows

Note: I'm using the latest source from SVN. (I need tasklet support...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cygwin is the only psuedo-supported way to compile the Mono class libraries on Windows.

You may be better off compiling them on Linux and then copying them over to Windows.

Comment: Yes.  All of Mono's class libraries are cross platform .net assemblies.

Comment: Just tried. Couldn't setup the pkg-cfg stuff correctly for glib under mingw. Arrg...